# Get total input cost of a product - CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP 4.x.
Assume that we have 3 tables in database:

```
1. Products
- title
- description
2. Recipes
- title
- unit
- input_price
3. Costs
- product_id
- recipe_id
- quantity
```

I want to calculate total input cost of all recipes of a single product.

- Which file should I write the function? Is it src/Model/Entity/Product.php ?
- How to write the fastest function to use many times?

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right src/Model/Entity/Product.php is the best place to write your function, your Product entity should have the infos about Recipes, but for that you must configure right your table models at src/Model/Table/ProductsTable.php.

Like this:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Recipes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'recipe_id',
        'joinTable' => 'Costs',
    ]);
```

more info: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations

And then at the controller you can use something like this:

```
$query = $products->find('all')->contain(['Recipes']);
foreach($query as $product){
  $product->yourEntityFunctionName()
}
```

OR you can use agregations functions: https://book.cakephp.org/4.next/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having